# Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type class and content type [text/html]

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I throw when post request via Rest Api, result is

> Content-Type: application/json

```
{
"error": "file content is not in the appropriate format",
"file_name": "15-10-2019-11-19-32_KKK.csv"
}
```

When I try code on my side, I use the below code

```
public RestTemplate restTemplateBuilder() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestTemplateHandler());
    return restTemplate;
  }
RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder();

ResponseEntity<FileUploadResponseDTO> serviceResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, FileUploadResponseDTO.class);
```

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [....FileUploadResponseDTO] and content type [text/html]
Gives a fault. how do I convert?

Comment: `public class FileUploadResponseDTO { `

  `public String error;`    **_<-- defined as private_**
  `public String file_name;`
  `public List<Long> data;`
  `public String ok;`

`-- getter setter`
it worked when I changed it to public and at the end of the url I use '/' more. Erased

Answer (score 0):

You can add content-type header to RestTemplate:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
```